# How to add Marker in Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to add Google maps in my application. I get maps successfully displayed in my application.

But the Problem is I am not getting my desired position.

```
static final LatLng vrrittihLocation = new LatLng(23.001779, 72.618946);
private GoogleMap googleMap;

if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        MarkerOptions Mo = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(vrrittihLocation)
                .title("Vrrittih Global Recruitment Consulting")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker));
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(vrrittihLocation, 18);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        googleMap.addMarker(Mo);
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker should be on ur maps, the reason u dont see your desired position maybe you can move your camera with following code.

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(vrrittihLocation)
                .zoom(18)
                .build();

CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);


googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Latitude and Longitude through **LocationManager** , Like Following ,

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {

        TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);

    }
```

and in overiden method onLocationChanged(...),

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
      latitude = location.getLatitude();
      longitude = location.getLongitude();
      LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
      googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

     locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
}
```

Hope this helpful to you...

Comment: Still it shows only map. not showing desire position.

Answer (score 0):

```
googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```